# How to edit Main Menu menu bar in Mac application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode5

Already I created a Mac app for my site but I can't find any guide on how to edit the Menu Bar items.

The only results I get are on how to make a status bar application.

I'd like to add items to the app's Main Menu: `App Name | File | Edit | View | etc.`

How can I add items to the main menu bar menu and then trigger actions when selected?

Comment: …Have you tried clicking on it?

Comment: Or have you tried reading the documentation? Xcode comes with lots of great documentation. Just click on the "Help" menu and open the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Just open `MainMenu.xib` and in the left navigation area expand Menu(under Objects) and you can find all Menu Items that appear on top here.

[image]

To add your own menu item drag a new menu item to this main menu. There are a lot of options for you to choose from:

[image]

Edit the menu items and add Actions like how you do it for any other object in Xib.

[image]

Comment: How do I make it link to like Paypal or Signin?

Comment: where do I find the file to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, for XCode 11, though you may think that the "menu bar" would be full of "menus," they are actually called "items." For each ITEM on the menu bar, you can have a menu associated.

1. First, add an item to the menu bar. It will have a name ("Item"), but the name won't be visible in the bar. Instead, you will see a blue placeholder.
2. You can now add a menu to the newly created item. By default, you should see three nameless sub-items (1, 2, and 3).
3. Name your new menu, and it should become visible in the menu bar.

Once you've managed to get your menu into the menu bar, it is easy enough to add menu items to it, move it, etc. I've found it easiest to drop the items into the hierarchical display of the `xib` on the left rather than onto the menu bar picture in the main editor.